# Cannot fix Auto Layout animation while rotation event

Tags: ios, swift, animation, autolayout

Don't be afraid of the huge code that will follow here. You can copy and paste the code snippet into a new single view application to see how it behaves. The problem sits somewhere inside the completion block of the animation executed alongside the rotation animation.

```
import UIKit

let sizeConstant: CGFloat = 60

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let topView = UIView()
    let backgroundView = UIView()
    let stackView = UIStackView()
    let lLayoutGuide = UILayoutGuide()
    let bLayoutGuide = UILayoutGuide()
    var bottomConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint]()
    var leftConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint]()

    var bLayoutHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    var lLayoutWidthConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        print(UIScreen.main.bounds)

        //        self.view.layer.masksToBounds = true

        let views = [
            UIButton(type: .infoDark),
            UIButton(type: .contactAdd),
            UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
        ]
        views.forEach(self.stackView.addArrangedSubview)

        self.backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        self.backgroundView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.view.addSubview(self.backgroundView)

        self.topView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        self.topView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.view.addSubview(self.topView)

        self.stackView.axis = isPortrait() ? .horizontal : .vertical
        self.stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
        self.stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.backgroundView.addSubview(self.stackView)

        self.topView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        self.topView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        self.topView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        self.topView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 46).isActive = true

        self.view.addLayoutGuide(self.lLayoutGuide)
        self.view.addLayoutGuide(self.bLayoutGuide)

        self.bLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        self.bLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        self.bLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        self.bLayoutHeightConstraint = self.bLayoutGuide.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: isPortrait() ? sizeConstant : 0)
        self.bLayoutHeightConstraint.isActive = true

        self.lLayoutGuide.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        self.lLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        self.lLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        self.lLayoutWidthConstraint = self.lLayoutGuide.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: isPortrait() ? 0 : sizeConstant)
        self.lLayoutWidthConstraint.isActive = true

        self.stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.backgroundView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        self.stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.backgroundView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        self.stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.backgroundView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        self.stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.backgroundView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true

        self.bottomConstraints = [
            self.backgroundView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
            self.backgroundView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
            self.backgroundView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),
            self.backgroundView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: sizeConstant)
        ]

        self.leftConstraints = [
            self.backgroundView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.lLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
            self.backgroundView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.lLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
            self.backgroundView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.lLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),
            self.backgroundView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: sizeConstant)
        ]

        if isPortrait() {

            NSLayoutConstraint.activate(self.bottomConstraints)

        } else {

            NSLayoutConstraint.activate(self.leftConstraints)
        }
    }

    override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {

        let willBePortrait = size.width < size.height

        coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: {

            context in

            let halfDuration = context.transitionDuration / 2.0

            UIView.animate(withDuration: halfDuration, delay: 0, options: .overrideInheritedDuration, animations: {

                self.bLayoutHeightConstraint.constant = 0
                self.lLayoutWidthConstraint.constant = 0
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

            }, completion: {

                _ in

                // HERE IS THE ISSUE!

                // Putting this inside `performWithoutAnimation` did not helped
                if willBePortrait {

                    self.stackView.axis = .horizontal
                    NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(self.leftConstraints)
                    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(self.bottomConstraints)

                } else {

                    self.stackView.axis = .vertical
                    NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(self.bottomConstraints)
                    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(self.leftConstraints)
                }
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

                UIView.animate(withDuration: halfDuration) {

                    if willBePortrait {

                        self.bLayoutHeightConstraint.constant = sizeConstant

                    } else {

                        self.lLayoutWidthConstraint.constant = sizeConstant
                    }
                    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                }
            })
        })

        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
    }

    func isPortrait() -> Bool {

        let size = UIScreen.main.bounds.size
        return size.width < size.height
    }
}
```

Here are a few screenshots of the issue I'm unable to solve. Look closely at the corners:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I'd assume that after reactivating different constraint array and force recalculation, the view would immediately snap to the layout guide, but as shown, it doesn't. Furthermore I don't understand why the red view is not in sync with the stack view, even if the stackview should always follow it's superview, which here is the red view.

PS: The best way to test it is the **iPhone X Plus simulator**.

Comment: have you tried on a real iphone X plus? It could be a great simulator bug.

Comment: The only way I could test is so far was by adding `window.layer.speed = 1 / 3.0` to the `AppDelegate`. The animation is very fast, but a good eye still can see the *white glitch*, when the redview is not snapped as it should. I don't own another iOS device to record a slowmotion video, to double check it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Use Size Classes

An entirely different approach to smoothly animate the toolbar animation is to leverage on the autoLayout size classes, specifically `hR` (height **Regular**) and `hC` (**height Compact**), and create different constraints for each.

[image: Horizontal to vertical]
[↻ replay animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ge3Rk.gif)

- A further improvement is to actually use two *distinct* toolbars, one for the vertical display, and one for the horizontal one. This is not by any mean a requirement, but it solves the resizing of the toolbar itself <sup>(†)</sup>.
- A final refinement is to implement these changes in Interface Builder, yielding exactly 0 lines of code, which of course is not mandatory either.

[image: Vertical to Horizontal]
[↻ replay animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xKOS.gif)

---

#### Zero Lines of Code

None of the proposed solutions tinker with `UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator` which not only greatly simplify the source code development and maintenance, it also doesn't need to rely on hardcoded values or supporting utilities. You also get a preview in **Interface Builder**. And once finalized in IB, you can still convert the logic to runtime programming if it is an absolute requirement.

- Notice that the `UIStackView` is embedded in the toolbar, and thus follows the animation. You can control the amount of *swing* of the toolbars out of sight by a constant ; I picked `1024` so that they move quickly out of the screen, and only reappear at the end of the transition.

  [image: Smooth]
- (†) Further leveraging on Interface Builder and size classes, you may still use a single toolbar, but if you do so it will resize during the transition. Again, the `UIStackView` is embedded, and its orientation is, too, *size classes* dependent, and the OS handles all the animation without the need to create a coordinator:

  [image: Size Classes]

  [image: Smooth too]

---

► Find this solution on [GitHub](https://github.com/SwiftArchitect/SO-41198069) and additional details on [Swift Recipes](http://swiftarchitect.com/recipes/#SO-41198069).

Comment: That's an interesting solution. One thing that makes me wonder if it's possible to determine when one of these views is offscreen so one could move the arranged subviews from one stack view to the other?! Is it a good idea to set a timer which will run alongside the coordinator and fire midway an event, where we could move our subviews to a different stack view?

Comment: One more off-topic question: how did you recorded the window like that (+ gif converter)?

Comment: You are welcome. #1: you are probably better off not doing any timing calculation: remember that my animation requires 2 distinct toolbars so that distortion is minimal between disappearance and reappearance. #2: Quicktime Player  + GIFBrewery

Answer (score 1):

> I'd assume that after reactivating different constraint array and force recalculation, the view would immediately snap to the layout guide, but as shown, it doesn't.

This isn't happening because you are activating/deactivating your constraints inside of the `coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition:completion:)` method. When you use this method, *everything* inside of the animation block will be animated along with your view controller's transition, so there will be no immediate snaps to the layout guide. If you wanted the red view and green view to immediately snap to their new positions before the rotation animation, then animate to fill their desired positions as the view controller is animating, then you could do something like this:

```swift
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {

    let willBePortrait = size.width < size.height

    self.bLayoutHeightConstraint.constant = 0
    self.lLayoutWidthConstraint.constant = 0

    if willBePortrait {
        self.stackView.axis = .horizontal
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(self.leftConstraints)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(self.bottomConstraints)
    } else {
        self.stackView.axis = .vertical
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(self.bottomConstraints)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(self.leftConstraints)
    }
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

    coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: { context in
        let halfDuration = context.transitionDuration / 2
        UIView.animate(withDuration: halfDuration, delay: halfDuration, animations: {
            if willBePortrait {
                self.bLayoutHeightConstraint.constant = sizeConstant
            } else {
                self.lLayoutWidthConstraint.constant = sizeConstant
            }
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        })
    })

    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
}
```

**EDIT:** If you want to animate the red view out while transitioning, and then animate the red view back in at the end, then that's a good time to use the coordinator, as the animation out can happen in the animation block and you can split the out- and in- blocks inside of it:

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {

    let willBePortrait = size.width < size.height

    if willBePortrait {
        self.stackView.axis = .horizontal
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(self.leftConstraints)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(self.bottomConstraints)
    } else {
        self.stackView.axis = .vertical
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(self.bottomConstraints)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(self.leftConstraints)
    }
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

    coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: { context in
        let halfDuration = context.transitionDuration / 2

        UIView.animate(withDuration: halfDuration, animations: {
            if willBePortrait {
                self.lLayoutWidthConstraint.constant = 0
            } else {
                self.bLayoutHeightConstraint.constant = 0
            }
        })
        UIView.animate(withDuration: halfDuration, delay: halfDuration, animations: {
            if willBePortrait {
                self.bLayoutHeightConstraint.constant = sizeConstant
            } else {
                self.lLayoutWidthConstraint.constant = sizeConstant
            }
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        })

    })
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
}
```

Comment: Hi Kevin Aleman, thank you for your answer. This approach contains only the half animation I want to achieve here. I wonder why calling the first half of the completion block inside `UIView.performWithoutAnimation { ... }` does not solve the problem here. Any clue? The rotation transition is another animation right? I want something similar to how the dock on the iPhone X Plus behaves in landscape. It hides and shows on a different side during the rotation.

Comment: Hey @DevAndArtist, I've updated my answer with the other half of the animation that you're trying to achieve. Note: This animation is based on your current view layout. To achieve what the Plus dock does in landscape, I think you're going to have to place your red view on an entirely different layer than the others in the VC. Notice how the dock does not begin to rotate as the rest of the view rotates; that indicates that it's completely separate from the other views in the hierarchy that are undergoing animation at that time. As far as `performWithoutAnimation`, I'm not sure why that happens.

Comment: Hi Kevin, your second approach is no different form the first one, I tested it, but I can also tell just from reading. Changing the constraints first will result in an instant snap, where there is no 'first half of the original animation' here. In general your approach is more like a workaround for my problem if there is really no other way. But I don't believe that it cannot be correctly solved, because other even more complex animations should be possible. This one is rather possible in a slightly different way as in OP or the current layout system is broken and I found some kind of a bug.

Comment: I probably let the bounty expire and come back after that and put a higher bounty to get more attention. :) Feel free to join and find the correct way `during the animation rotation`. I really want this animation to work as intended.